# Чтение dat idx файлов

Tags: format, база-данных, datatable, файлы

Здравствуйте. Хотел спросить, кто-нибудь читал dat idx файлы? Знаю, что они могут быть разных форматов, но есть ли нормальное решение и как их правильно прочитать? Готов использовать любой язык, но желательно C#.

Comment: Боюсь, что dat файлы могут быть "абсолютно с любым содержанием". Но всемогущий open открывает любой файл (или как оно там в шарпе называется - FileStream?).

Это могут быть файлы базы данных (даже самопальной) или SCADA CIMPLICITY. Поэтому для начала определите, что именно вы собрались парсить.

Comment: KoVadim, да как раз это я и делаю сейчас. А вы не знаете случайно, что было популярным где-то в середине 90х ? какой из движков?

Comment: Для начала - dbase, foxpro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@semenvx27](/users/7098/semenvx27)](/users/7098/semenvx27), IDX (равно как и NDX) файлы - это индексные файлы легендарной [dBase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase). А DAT файлы - это SQL'ные таблицы поздних клонов dBase. Вообще было множество сишных либ, которые работали с dBase клонами.

Что вас конкретно интересует? Если получать просто данные, то проще цепляться через ODBC - трудно представить, что нужно спецом парсить нутрянку этих файлов...

Под dBase я понимаю: собствено сам dBase, потом Fox/FoxPlus, далее Clipper и потом под занавес Foxpro, на котором вся эта история и закончилась.

**Update**

Я тут подумал, проще всего, наверное, поднять на виртуалке Win95, запустить на нем Foxpro и прочитать все это хозяйство с последующим экспортом в другой более современный формат или хотя бы в CSV. Foxpro как последнее издыхании легенды dBase должен понимать все предыдущие форматы. Да, и IDX читать бессмысленно, это индексные файлы, для вас интерес представляют только DAT файлы.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: @semenvx27, прочтите апдейт ответа.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, попробовал открыть use ".../file.dat", но FoxPro сказал Is Not a Table. Я подозреваю, что и предыдущие версии не заработают, потому что есть подозрение на CUSTOM format. Спасибо за ответ, однако нельзя сказать, что проблему легко решить (если ее вообще можно решить).

Comment: Можешь вывесить заголовок DAT файла в HEX'е (ну типа первые 32 байта)?

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ 1a ff 5d fe 34 00 b9 01 01 00 8c d8 00 00 00 00 00 00 a6 80 00 00 00 04 10 20 00 00 5c 88 00 00 c8 0f 01 00 18 9b 01 00 38 11 02 00 7c 5d 02 00 74 95 02 00 64 cc 02 00

Comment: Увы, ни о чем не говорит :(